# SQL alias inside a Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn some SQL, and I feel like I should be able to do this, but I get a syntax error.

```
SELECT Score,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Score s) FROM Scores WHERE s >= Score) AS Rank
FROM Scores
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

It allows me to do

```
# Write your MySQL query statement below
SELECT Score s,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Score) FROM Scores WHERE Score >= s) AS Rank
FROM Scores
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

but for the question the first column has to be named `Score`.

I've seen other answers for this problem that seem really complicated, but if anyone has a simple way to make this idea work I'd appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: See about `HAVING`

Comment: Rank becomes a reserved word on version 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT s.Score,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Score) FROM Scores s2 WHERE s2.Score >= s.Score) AS Rank
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY s.Score DESC;
```

Note that I aliases both table references and all column references.

Of course, this is simpler:

```
select s.score,
       dense_rank() over (order by s.score desc) as rank
from scores s
order by s.score desc;
```